# How to jump back to the previous window in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling

There is one video and if I click on that video it will open in a new tab. If I again click on that tab the control should navigate back to the previous tab.

Answer (score 0):

You can go back to the previous window with this syntax:

```
window.history.go(-1)
```